# Thucydides изменить property файл, чтобы ожидало подгрузку страницы не 5 сек, а более

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Вот получаю такую ошибку, когда страница которую я ожидаю получить и инициализировать на ней элементы не загружается более 5 сек:

```
net.serenitybdd.core.exceptions.SerenityManagedException: Timed out after 5 seconds waiting for net.serenitybdd.core.pages.WebElementFacadeImpl
```

Есть ли вариант изменить время ожидания загрузки ?
Если есть какой-нибудь файл с тем какие проперти вообще есть и как правильно их указывать буду рад почитать. 
В доках не нашел, но нашел там такие проперти

```
WEBDRIVER_WAIT_FOR_TIMEOUT = 60
WEBDRIVER_TIMEOUTS_IMPLICITLYWAIT = 60
THUCYDIDES_TIMEOUT=60
```

Однако такое написание пропертей видимо не работает и нужно что-то типа

```
serenity.webdriver.timeout=x.
```

Указал ожидание в пропертях webdriver.timeouts.implicitlywait=60, получил туже ошибку:

```
[main] INFO net.thucydides.core.util.PropertiesFileLocalPreferences -       webdriver.driver=firefox
[main] INFO net.thucydides.core.util.PropertiesFileLocalPreferences - serenity.project.name=EE Shop Automation
[main] INFO net.thucydides.core.util.PropertiesFileLocalPreferences - serenity.take.screenshots=FOR_FAILURES
[main] INFO net.thucydides.core.util.PropertiesFileLocalPreferences - webdriver.timeouts.implicitlywait=60

net.serenitybdd.core.exceptions.SerenityManagedException: Timed out after 5   seconds waiting for net.serenitybdd.core.pages.WebElementFacadeImpl$1@5e9e7d08
Build info: version: '2.50.1', revision: 'd7fc91b29de65b790abb01f3ac5f7ea2191c88a7', time: '2016-01-29 11:11:26'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мой фейл, сам спросил сам отвечую Вот тут лежат проперти с описанием:
[док](http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity-staging/#_running_serenity_tests_from_the_command_line)

И нужно обязательно указывать в милисекундах 60 сек = 60000 милисекунд ! =)